# Use split to create new string

Tags: c#

I'm using Split to pick different parts of a long string. Then I also use Split to rebuild the same string back to a long string again, but without the first part of the string

```
string.Split(',')[1] + "," + string.Split(',')[2] + "," + string.Split(',')[3] ....
```

The string I'm using

```
string info = "id,title,director,actor1,actor2,actor3,genre,runtime,year,comment";
```

My question is if there is a simple and uncomplicated way to rebuild the string without using Split like I do? Since I want all parts of the string without the first part, the id, then there should be a simple way to just remove every thing before the first comma sign?

Comment: What do you want the parts for? Can you show what you do **before** you rebuild the string again?

Comment: I'm using it like this to set values to components in a windows form: lblInfo1.Text = movieManager.GetMovieFromList(index).Split(',')[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you do not know the length of the substrings, but you want to cut away everything before the first comma (including the comma) so the simplest thing to do is probably looking for the position of this comma and then take everything after that:

```
int idx = info.IndexOf(',');
string result = info.Substring(idx + 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are over complicating things:

```
info = info.SubString(info.IndexOf(',') + 1);
```

The first one is faster, this one is just for completeness sake:

```
info = info.Remove(0, info.IndexOf(',') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point splitting the same string over and over again. Furthermore, joining a string can be done using String.Join

You write:

```
var str="moo,id,title,director,actor1,actor2,actor3,genre,runtime,year,comment";
var parts=str.Split(',');
var newStr=String.Join(",",parts,1,parts.Length-1);
Console.WriteLine(newStr);
```

Even better though is to use IndexOf to find the first occurence of ',' and return the string after the first comma:

```
    var newStr=str.Substring(str.IndexOf(',')+1);
```

If you want to separate the first element from the rest of the string, you can do this using Substring:

```
    var firstComma=str.IndexOf(',');
    var newStr=str.Substring(firstComma+1);
    var firstStr=str.Substring(0,firstComma);
```